# Attempted import error : 'required' is not exported from 'yup'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm

Hello everyone I've Installed the yup in my new project but after importing it i'm getting the following error . required is not exported . I tried to change the position of import like putting it on top but still nothing happens please help I have to add validations on my react App.Thanks

I'm using following libraries in my App

```
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
"axios": "^0.24.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"datatables.net-bs4": "^1.11.3",
"date-fns": "^2.26.0",
"formik": "^2.2.9",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
"react-day-picker": "^7.4.10",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"react-toastify": "^8.1.0",
"react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
"react-yup": "^1.23.0",
"web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
"yup": "^0.32.11"
```

},

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a schema type like `Yup.string()` or `Yup.number()` before you can use `required()`.

Only schemas have the `required` prop:

```
BaseSchema, MixedSchema, BooleanSchema, StringSchema, NumberSchema, DateSchema, ObjectSchema, ArraySchema
```

It's not directly exported from Yup.